# Is there a way to update a database from a streamlit website?

Tags: python, sql, database, streamlit

I am fairly new to data science and coding. Over the past few months, I've been messing around with streamlit to create a simple website for one of my projects. Everything is going well, it's just that as I learn more, I have new ideas which call for changes to the foundation of the data for the streamlit site.

Recently I've started to learn about databases. I think a database would allow for a more efficiently running site. However, I know streamlit uses GitHub for deployment and I was wondering if it was possible for me to create a database for my streamlit site that can be updated directly from the streamlit site when there is new data. That way I don't have to commit to GitHub any new updates manually from my computer.

By the way, I haven't actually started making a database. I've just been watching videos learning about them. So I guess any free database options would be fine.

Comment: I don't know what server you use but on many servers you can send code directly on server without GitHub. And even if you use GitHub there is no problem to use database